Fastest quasi-random function in 6502?
I am hacking around with the Oric Atmos computer, and it has an interesting video display scheme, involving attribute values which change the behaviour (ink/paper colours, blinking, invert) according to a certain bit value.
For the fun of it, I'm using a function to generate a 'weird',  'quasi-random' set of data, to exercise the Orics' attribute system,

'quasi-random', because in fact the Oric RND function starts with a seed, and that means you can always get the same random set of data with the same seed,
and in this case, additionally 'weird' in that I filter out a set of attribute ranges from the value returned from RND, in order to not trigger attribute clash and 'strange video' results when these bytes are blasted into the Oric's HIRES screen buffer region.

So, here's the playground function in C, with some curiously-commented code - more on that after the code:
void gen_rnd_colors()
{

    int j;
    int k;

    volatile char rg;
    char s;

    // s = peek(0x276);
    // seed_lfsr(s);

    // j .. memory .. k
    j = (unsigned int) HIRES_START;
    k = (unsigned int) HIRES_START + 320 * 3;
    //k = (unsigned int)HIRES_END;

    do {
        // rg = 16+((qrandomJ(peek(0x276)) % 255) & 7);
        // // Somewhat slow C-based implementation with assembly RNG - works
        do {
            rg = qrandomJ(peek(0x276)) % 255;
        }
        while (((rg & 0x78) == 0x08 || (rg & 0x78) == 0x18)
               || ((rg & 0x78) == 0x88 || (rg & 0x78) == 0x98));

        // rg = qrandomJ(peek(0x276)) % 255;

        // Linear-feedback shift register method
        // rg = lfsr_random();

        // table-based with
        // rg = fastbloop();

        // Chema's randgen:
        // rg == randgen();

        poke(j, rg);
        // printf("j: %x rg: %x\n", j, rg);

    }
    while (j++ < k);

}

The key bit, which I want to do in assembly eventually, is this:
... (((rg & 0x78) == 0x08 || (rg & 0x78) == 0x18)
               || ((rg & 0x78) == 0x88 || (rg & 0x78) == 0x98));

I've tried a few different approaches so far, just to teach myself some 6502 and have some fun - the pre-generated table case (which is obvious but cheesy), the lfsr approach (which I don't fully understand yet - the assembly here comes from my naive understanding, coupled with some non-answers from AI), so there are holes in all of this.
In the commented code above, there are different implementations of this random function, which do/do-not work in various ways.
Here is the existing assembly code:
; qrandom.s - experiment with different ways to generate 'valid' colour values randomly
_qrandomJ
        ldy #8
        lda $0
_qrback
        asl
        rol $FF
        bcc _qrnoEor
        eor #$39
_qrnoEor
        dey
        bne _qrback
;       jmp return_qrandomJ

_qrCont
        cmp #24
        bcc _qrnd_next          ; If number is below 8, it's valid
        cmp #28
        bcc _qrandomJ           ; If number below 28, regen

_qrnd_next:
        cmp #152
        bcc return_qrandomJ
        cmp #156
        bcc _qrandomJ

return_qrandomJ:
        sta $0
        cmp #0
        rts

_lfsr
   .byt 20,42        ; 16-bit LFSR storage (2 bytes)

; Seed the LFSR with an initial value
; Input: A = low byte, X = high byte (seed values)
_seed_lfsr:
    sta _lfsr          ; Store A in the low byte of LFSR
    stx _lfsr+1        ; Store X in the high byte of LFSR
    rts               ; Return

; LFSR random number generator
; Output: A = random number between 0–255, excluding 8-18 and 88-98
_lfsr_random:
    ; Load the current LFSR value
    lda _lfsr
    ldx _lfsr+1

    ; Perform the LFSR shift and feedback (16-bit LFSR with polynomial)
    lda _lfsr+1        ; Load high byte
    lsr               ; Shift right (low bit goes into carry)
    ror _lfsr          ; Rotate carry into low byte
    lda _lfsr+1        ; Reload high byte
    ror               ; Rotate carry into high byte
    lda _lfsr          ; Load low byte (A)
    eor #$B4          ; XOR feedback with a chosen polynomial value
    sta _lfsr          ; Store back into LFSR low byte

    ; Get the new random number (low byte of LFSR)
    lda _lfsr

    ; Check for exclusion range 8-18 (0x08–0x12)
check_exclusion:
    cmp #8
    bcc return_random   ; If number is below 8, it's valid
    cmp #19
    bcs check_next      ; If number is above 18, go to next check

    ; If we are here, the number is in the excluded range 8-18, generate again
    jmp _lfsr_random

check_next:
    ; Check for exclusion range 88-98 (0x58–0x62)
    cmp #88
    bcc return_random   ; If number is below 88, it's valid
    cmp #99
    bcs return_random   ; If number is above 98, it's valid

    ; If we are here, the number is in the excluded range 88-98, generate again
    jmp _lfsr_random

return_random:
    rts               ; Return with the valid random number in A

; Example usage:
; 1. Call 'seed_lfsr' to initialize the LFSR.
; 2. Call '_lfsr_random' to obtain random numbers, excluding 8-18 and 88-98.


// Chema's RNG from https://forum.defence-force.org/viewtopic.php?p=19108&hilit=random#p19108
; A real random generator... 
randseed .word $dead    ; will it be $dead again? 

_randgen
.(
   lda randseed         ; get old lsb of seed. 
   ora $308     ; lsb of VIA T2L-L/T2C-L. 
   rol          ; this is even, but the carry fixes this. 
   adc $304     ; lsb of VIA TK-L/T1C-L.  This is taken mod 256. 
   sta randseed         ; random enough yet. 
   sbc randseed+1       ; minus the hsb of seed... 
   rol          ; same comment than before.  Carry is fairly random. 
   sta randseed+1       ; we are set. 

    cmp #8
    bcc return_randgen   ; If number is below 8, it's valid
    cmp #19
    bcs check_nxt      ; If number is above 18, go to next check

    ; If we are here, the number is in the excluded range 8-18, generate again
    jmp _randgen

check_nxt:
    ; Check for exclusion range 88-98 (0x58–0x62)
    cmp #88
    bcc return_randgen   ; If number is below 88, it's valid
    cmp #99
    bcs return_randgen   ; If number is above 98, it's valid

    ; If we are here, the number generated is in the excluded range, so regenerate 
    jmp _randgen

return_randgen:
   rts          ; see you later alligator. 
.)



// Chema's RNG from https://forum.defence-force.org/viewtopic.php?p=19108&hilit=random#p19108
; A real random generator... 
_randgenJ
.(
   lda randseed         ; get old lsb of seed. 
   ora $308     ; lsb of VIA T2L-L/T2C-L. 
   rol          ; this is even, but the carry fixes this. 
   adc $304     ; lsb of VIA TK-L/T1C-L.  This is taken mod 256. 
   sta randseed         ; random enough yet. 
   sbc randseed+1       ; minus the hsb of seed... 
   rol          ; same comment than before.  Carry is fairly random. 
   sta randseed+1       ; we are set. 

    cmp #24
    bcc check_nxtJ          ; If number is below 8, it's valid
    cmp #28
    bcc _randgenJ           ; If number below 28, regen
check_nxtJ:
    cmp #152
    bcc return_randgenJ
    cmp #156
    bcc _randgenJ

return_randgenJ:
   rts          ; see you later alligator. 
.)


The code for fastbloop:
; qrandom.s - experiment with different ways to generate 'valid' colour values randomly using a lookup table

; -----------------------------------------------------
; Random number table (pre-filtered values)
; Excludes values where (r & 0x78) == 0x08, 0x18, 0x88, 0x98

random_table:
    .byte $00, $01, $02, $03, $04, $05, $06, $07
    .byte $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17
    .byte $20, $21, $22, $23, $24, $25, $26, $27
    .byte $30, $31, $32, $33, $34, $35, $36, $37
    .byte $40, $41, $42, $43, $44, $45, $46, $47
    .byte $50, $51, $52, $53, $54, $55, $56, $57
    .byte $60, $61, $62, $63, $64, $65, $66, $67
    .byte $70, $71, $72, $73, $74, $75, $76, $77
    .byte $80, $81, $82, $83, $84, $85, $86, $87
    .byte $A0, $A1, $A2, $A3, $A4, $A5, $A6, $A7
    .byte $B0, $B1, $B2, $B3, $B4, $B5, $B6, $B7
    .byte $C0, $C1, $C2, $C3, $C4, $C5, $C6, $C7
    .byte $D0, $D1, $D2, $D3, $D4, $D5, $D6, $D7
    .byte $E0, $E1, $E2, $E3, $E4, $E5, $E6, $E7
    .byte $F0, $F1, $F2, $F3, $F4, $F5, $F6, $F7

    ; Seed for random number generation
seed: .byte $42
_fastbloop:

    lda $276           ; Load seed for random function
    sta seed

    lda #$02           ; Initialize high byte for storing in page $0200
    sta addr_high      ; Store in high byte variable
    lda #$00           ; Initialize low byte
    sta addr_low

    lda #$00           ; Initialize iteration counter
    sta iteration_count

start_loop:
    ldx #$00           ; X-register for indexing the table
    lda seed
    jsr _randgen        ; _qrandomJ      ; Call random generator
    tax                ; Store random result in X for indexing

    lda random_table, x ; Get a random value from the table

    ; Calculate the address to store the value
    lda addr_high       ; Load the high byte of the address
    sta temp_high       ; Store in temporary variable
    lda addr_low        ; Load the low byte of the address
    sta temp_low        ; Store in temporary variable

    ; Store the value at the address (absolute indexed)
    sta temp_store      ; Save the random value temporarily
    ldy #$00            ; Clear Y for addressing calculation

    ; Form full address manually
    lda temp_low        ; Load low byte of address
    sta $00             ; Save it to memory
    lda temp_high       ; Load high byte of address
    sta $01             ; Save it to memory

    ; Store value using absolute indexed addressing
    lda temp_store
    sta ($00), y        ; Store value at the address

    ; Increment the low byte of the address
    inc addr_low        
    lda addr_low        ; Check if low byte has overflowed
    bne continue_loop   ; If not overflowed, continue

    inc addr_high       ; Increment high byte if low byte overflowed

continue_loop:
    ; Increment the iteration counter
    inc iteration_count
    lda iteration_count
    cmp #$10            ; Set the loop to run for 16 iterations (or another value)
    beq done            ; If iterations reached the limit, exit the loop

    jmp start_loop      ; Otherwise, loop back

done:
    lda random_table, x  ; Return the last random value in A register
    rts                 ; Return to C with value in A


; Temporary variables for address calculations
temp_high:     .byte $00
temp_low:      .byte $00
temp_store:    .byte $00
addr_low:      .byte $00  ; High and low byte variables
addr_high:     .byte $00
iteration_count: .byte $00 ; Loop counter


The Question:
What is the fastest way to get a quasi-random (repeatable from seed) number from 0..255, excluding any values in the ranges 0x8..0x18,and 0x88..0x98, in 6502 Assembly Code?
Bonus followup-question: where did I go wrong in any of the above implementations?

The usual term is “pseudorandom” – quasirandomness is apparently something different: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuasirandomSequence.html

Your question isn't really well defined unless you specify criteria for the quality of randomness that is to be produced.  I mean, this RNG could be extremely fast...

(r & 0x78) can never be 0x88 or 0x98.

Add one is really fast, and pseudorandom for some definition of 'pseudo'. Grabbing lower 8 bits off the system clock might be fast and more pseudo...

@JonCuster grabbing bits off the system clock fails the requirement "repeatable from seed".

@JeremyP - except one can usually set the system clock to an initial value. The end result is not particularly different from just adding 1, plus/minus DRAM refresh timing.

Unless you nail down what you mean by "quasi-random", there won't be a single "fastest". There are different algorithms to generate pseudo-random numbers, and better "quality" of randomness will often require a more involved algorithms to get better statistical properties. The wikipedia page lists some approaches.

And if "repeatable from seed" is your only criterion for "quasi-random", you could just count from the seed onward, excluding your ranges (which would be very fast). So clearly you need some other criteria for "randomness".

0x38 & 0x78 = 0x38, which is not 0x08, 0x18, 0x88, or 0x98.  Why is it excluded from random_table?  random_table only has 120 entries so lda random_table,x where x>119 will give you an unexpected value. But that's doesn't even matter because the next instruction is lda addr_high so the table lookup is forgotten.

Also, if it's a fixed number and rather low number, and 'from seed', one can as well have a sequence of sufficient length prepared, stored as data table. Fastest possible it eliminates all calculation beyond pointer increment. Might even save space as you program is already a good $200 bytes, isn't it? Lookup is 2-6 instructions plus table.

@NateEldredge What, no xkcd?!

Shouldn't those excluded ranges be inclusive at the low end and exclusive at the high end?

You may want to read up on the theory of random numbers. Art of computer programming is the definite source.

generate a 7 bit random number (bbbbbbb), shift it to have bit3 zero (bbbb0bbb), and retry if the upper nibble is 9

@gidds xkcd is overrated.

@Tommylee2k: 6502 only has rotate-by-1 so it would take 4 rol or ror instructions to do that.  (https://www.masswerk.at/6502/6502_instruction_set.html).  Unless there's a nibble-swap like AVR's swap, but I don't think there is.  So I think the suggestion in my answer is a more efficient range check.  Also, they want all 222 allowed bit-patterns to be possible, I assume.  If you start with a 7-bit number you only have 128.  (I'm assuming 0x8..0x18 is inclusive at both ends, so includes 17 numbers, so there can't just be a single bit to check.)

"Anyone who considers arithmetical methods of producing random digits is, of course, in a state of sin,” -- John von Neumann.

@JonCuster "Repeatable from seed" to me means exactly repeatable. This means it has to be a pseudorandom sequence.

@PeterCordes I was refering to the table, and ignored the misleading "r & 0x78 may not be 0x98" (which is never true) and that's 0xbbbb0bbb with (result & 0xf0) == 0x90 rerolled

If the number falls into one of the ranges you want to reject, a simple option is to just keep looping and generate another number.  If you're considering a 256-byte table, though, you could I guess invent a mapping from an arbitrary 8-bit number to numbers that avoid your bad ranges, but a mapping from 256 inputs to 256 - 17*2 = 222 outputs would have some values twice, some once, so would be biased.  That small amount of bias might not matter to you, especially if you're considering a very fast but low quality PRNG.

Checking for those two ranges should be simple.  They have the same length, and they differ only in whether a single bit was set.  This is the same situation as ASCII upper/lower case, so the same tricks apply.  (My answer there explains why sub and an unsigned-compare works as a range-check.)
In C written one assembly operation at a time so it's easy to translate:
   x = prng();      // inline it or call a function
   tmp = x & 0x7F;  // clear high bit, mapping high values into the lower half
   tmp -= 0x08;     // range-shift from 0x08..0x18  to  0 .. 0x10
   if (tmp < 0x11u)   // unsigned compare
        goto retry_prng;   // back to top of loop to generate another random number.
   // fall-through path: 
   // x is a random value not in the ranges you're avoiding

Assuming you work on tmp in the accumulator, you need x saved somewhere else because the and isn't reversible (unlike the sub).  But that's probably still worth it vs. 2x sub+cmp+branch then an add to restore the original after two separate range-checks.
Perhaps saved into video memory, so if it wasn't in the bad range you can just leave it there and increment your pointer.  And if it was bad, you'll overwrite it several cycles later.  I don't know how crazy the effects are for these attributes: if scan-out seeing even one of them makes the whole screen go crazy, then that's not a good option since it's possible with unlucky timing.
For PRNG choice, "AX+ Tinyrand" self-modifying code from https://codebase64.org/doku.php?id=base:ax_tinyrand8 (from lvd's link-only answer) looks good, although it needs a function to condition the seed to a long-period state, so some different seeds map to same starting point.  It also only produces 8 bits at a time.  That's ok since you need to check each 8-bit value separately. See also https://codebase64.org/doku.php?id=base:comparison_of_6502_random_generators for a comparison of 8-bit and 16-bit PRNGs, mostly with 16-bit state.
You do need a lot of random data so an Xorshift producing 16 bits at a time (in less than twice as many clock cycles as AX+ takes to produce 8) could be usable too.  But then you'll have extra overhead of loading one half back into the accumulator, which would eat into its speed advantage.

If you don’t care about the quality of your random numbers, the fastest and shortest algorithm is probably this algortihm for an 8-bit value (based on a posting by White Flame at Codebase64):
If you care more about speed:
seed=*+1
    lda #$42
    beq doEor
    asl
    bcc noEOR
doEOR:
    eor #$1d
noEOR:
    sta seed

Length: 12 bytes
Execution time: 11...14 cycles
But the numbers from this algorithm show some regular patters, best seen when plotting subsequent numbers.
If you are looking for something practical you would rather want something like XORshift789:
seedhigh=*+1
    lda #$33
    lsr
seedlow=*+1
    lda #$33
    ror
    eor seedhigh
    sta seedhigh   ; high part of x ^= x << 7 done
    ror             ; A has now x >> 9 and high bit comes from low byte
    eor seedlow
    sta seedlow    ; x ^= x >> 9 and the low part of x ^= x << 7 done
    eor seedhigh 
    sta seedhigh   ; x ^= x << 8 done

Length: 25 bytes
Execution time: 34 cycles
This algorithm works fine for calculating either an 8 bit or16 bit number without a visual pattern. When seeding, you have to avoid a seed of $0000 (so either hibyte or lobyte must be non-zero).
You might want to add an RTS at the end of either algorithm to use it as subroutine, so it would be 1 byte and 6 cycles more.
Both implementations here use self-modification, so they need to be changed if you write ROM code. Using zero-page addresses instead of self-modification can shave off a couple of cycles for the Xorshift implementation.

I'm a bit partial to--if I'm remembering how I did things:
lsr partOne
lda partTwo
rol
bcc okay
eor #$DB
sta partTwo
eor PartOne

5+3+2+(3 or 4)+3+3 = 20 cycles for code running from ROM and using zero-page, not counting a JSR or RTS.  Code running out of zero page could shave a couple of cycles, but would more likely need a JSR or RTS.
This requires initialization with a non-zero seed, but if memory serves it will yield a sequence of length 65535 which includes every pair of numbers once each except (0,0)
